# How to convert part of dataframe to vector

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame having sentiment scores for user ratings. I need to convert them to vectors to use in another script. How can I do that? Any help is appreciated.

**Input:**

[image: Input]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**Data:**

```
{'Group': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G2', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G2'},
 'User': {0: 'User1',
  1: 'User2',
  2: 'User2',
  3: 'User3',
  4: 'User3',
  5: 'User4'},
 'Sentiment': {0: 'positive',
  1: 'positive',
  2: 'negative',
  3: 'positive',
  4: 'negative',
  5: 'negative'},
 '#No of Reviews': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 6}}
```

In the above data, I need to convert `G1->User1->positive->5 to G1->User1->[5, 0]`. 5 for positive, 0 for negative.

Comment: What python package are you using to for your dataframe?

Comment: @Tzane, I used the 'pandas' package to load the data and just added the 'pandas' tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```py
def foo(df):
    result = []
    for i in ['positive', 'negative']:
        sentiment = df.loc[df['Sentiment']==i, '#No of Reviews'].values
        if sentiment.size > 0:
            result.append(sentiment[0])
        else: 
            result.append(0)   
    return result

df.groupby(['Group', 'User']).apply(foo)

Group  User 
G1     User1    [5, 0]
       User2    [5, 4]
G2     User3    [4, 4]
       User4    [0, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you, @padu. Both your and the above solution by Timus is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that you are using Pandas (your question doesn't have a tag that indicates what tool you are using, and the concept of a dataframe isn't unique)?

Then you could use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html?highlight=pivot_table#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) (`df`: your dataframe):

```
df = df.pivot_table(
        index=["Group", "User"], columns="Sentiment", fill_value=0
     ).droplevel(0, axis="columns")
df["Vec"] = [[p, n] for p, n in zip(df.positive, df.negative)]
df["Norm"] = [
    [1 if p else 0, 1 if n else 0] for p, n in zip(df.positive, df.negative)
]
```

Result:

```
Sentiment    negative  positive     Vec    Norm
Group User                                     
G1    User1         0         5  [5, 0]  [1, 0]
      User2         4         5  [5, 4]  [1, 1]
G2    User3         4         4  [4, 4]  [1, 1]
      User4         6         0  [0, 6]  [0, 1]
```

You could replace the list comprehensions with:

```
df["Vec"] = df[["positive", "negative"]].apply(list, axis=1)
df["Norm"] = df[["positive", "negative"]].astype(bool).astype(int).apply(list, axis=1)
```

If needed, you can drop the `negative`/`positive`-columns and/or reset the index afterwards:

```
df = df.drop(columns=["negative", "positive"]).reset_index(drop=False)
df.columns.name = None
```

```
  Group   User     Vec    Norm
0    G1  User1  [5, 0]  [1, 0]
1    G1  User2  [5, 4]  [1, 1]
2    G2  User3  [4, 4]  [1, 1]
3    G2  User4  [0, 6]  [0, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Timus, for the response. It is working well for my question. And I am using Pandas to load the data. I will add the tag to the question.